# SQL JOIN and CASE

Tags: sql

I hope you can help me with this simple query that I've been working on for a few days. I am new to SQL and have read answers to similar questions, but did not find what I was looking for.

My goal is to query information from two different tables, and display it in a readable manner. I was successful in creating the following query, which displays all of the information I need:

```
SELECT
    PA.EntityName,
    PA.EntityType,
    PO.Name,
    PO.Feature
FROM PolicyAssociations PA
JOIN Policies PO ON PO.Id = PA.PolicyId
WHERE
    PA.EntityType='1'
    or
    PA.EntityType='2'
GROUP by PO.Name, PA.EntityName
```

Now I need to change the output of the EntityType column (displayed as 'Object Type') from numerical values to text, e.g. display the word 'Computer' instead of '1' and 'User' instead of '2'.

The following query works independently, but I have failed to incorporate these strings into the main JOIN query in many variations:

```
SELECT EntityType,
CASE
  WHEN EntityType = '1' THEN 'Computer'
  WHEN EntityType = '2' THEN 'User'
END
FROM policyassociations
```

Comment: Can you please share a [failed] attempt and explain what exactly was the problem?

Comment: Why do you need a `GROUP BY` ? no aggregation is occurring; do you want to `ORDER BY` instead?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just mean this?  Seems too basic of a solution.

```
SELECT
    PA.EntityName,
    CASE WHEN EntityType = '1' THEN 'Computer'
        WHEN EntityType = '2' THEN 'User'END as EntityTypeStr,
    PA.EntityType,
    PO.Name,
    PO.Feature
FROM PolicyAssociations PA
JOIN Policies PO ON PO.Id = PA.PolicyId
WHERE
    PA.EntityType='1'
    or
    PA.EntityType='2'
```

Comment: Sorry I disappeared, had to drop this and re-prioritize, but I'm back at it now.

First of all - thanks @Liss! That solved it.

I am now trying to do the same thing with another column, which has fields that look like this:

Comment: This completely depends on the type of database you're using. You could looking into regex for that type.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
SELECT
    PA.EntityName,
    PA.EntityType,
    PO.Name,
    PO.Feature,
    CASE WHEN PA.EntityType = '1' THEN 'Computer' ELSE 'User' END [Object Type]
FROM PolicyAssociations PA
INNER JOIN Policies PO 
     ON PO.Id = PA.PolicyId
WHERE
    PA.EntityType IN ('1','2') -- Why are these values not INTs?
ORDER by PO.Name, PA.EntityName;
```